# Best testing for observable in template

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, angular-components

Here's the component under test:

```js
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-search',
  templateUrl: 'search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['search.component.css'],
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  things: Observable<Thing[]>;

  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.things = this.searchTerms
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap((term: string) => term
        ? this.searchService.search(term)
        : Observable.of<Thing[]>([]));
  }

  search(term: string) {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }
}
```

And here's the search.component.html:

```html
<form (submit)="search()">
  <input #searchBox (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<div *ngIf="(things | async)?.length == 0; else searchResults">No things found.</div> 
<ng-template #searchResults>
  <div class="search-results">
    <div *ngFor="let thing of things | async" class="search-result">
      {{thing.id}}
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

And here's the failing test:

```html
it('should exhibit issue', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.search('123');
    tick(300);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.things.subscribe((things) => {
        // This fails. (I've tried various things, this is just the latest attempt.)
        expect(dom.querySelectorAll('.search-results .search-result').length).toBe(1);
    });
}));
```

[Here's a plunk with what I've got so far.](https://embed.plnkr.co/wS2H5PzU2SR2LOZLCnOj/)

I don't see changes to the DOM no matter what I do. `fixture.detectChanges()` doesn't do anything to the DOM.

**How do you test Observables?**

Comment: Doing `component.things.subscribe()` is unnecessary in the unit test. You have test what has changed in the component after you call `component.search('123');`.
If something has to change in template, then select respective element in template using class or ID and test it. If value of property has to change then test that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149398/discussion-between-ricksmt-and-karan-garg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. You can check [the plunk (version 25)](https://embed.plnkr.co/wS2H5PzU2SR2LOZLCnOj/), but here's the condensed solution:

```
it('now works!', async(() => {
    // Initialize the component.
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // The Observable is now initialized and we can now subscribe.
    component.things.subscribe((things) => {
        // Now that we've got the data, look for changes.
        fixture.detectChanges();

        // The DOM/view should now be up to date.
        expect(dom.querySelectorAll('.search-results .search-result').length).toBe(1);
    });

    // Initiate stuff happening.
    component.search('123');
}));
```

Highlights:

- Use `async` instead of `fakeAsync`.
- Remember to call `detectChanges` in your subscription so that the view updates.

One thing I'd like to note: whether the `subscribe` came before or after the event (the call to `search` in the example) didn't seem to matter in this case. I've placed it before as a precaution because a 'hot' Observable might process the event before the `subscribe` registers; the observer would then miss the notification, the callback would never fire, and the test would be void.

Comment: Unfortunatly, this doesn't work if the Observable is provided by MockNgRedux / Redux store ;(

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
app.search('123');
tick(400);
fixture.detectChanges();
const searchNodes = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.search-results .search-result')).map((item) => item.nativeElement);
expect(searchNodes.length).toBe(3);
```

Comment: `tick` only works in `fakeAsync`, and `fakeAsync` won't retrieve the external template.